# Confused about function declarations and prototypes

Tags: function, call, declaration

I have a simple question but its bugging me. My online text book says this is true --> "A function declaration enables calls to the function before the function definition." I thought this was false because if a function is called only after it was declared, how does the program know what it does. I figured it would cause a compile time error. Can someone explain why this is true? thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific language involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that once you **declare** the function, the compiler will know about it's existence.

So you can then write code that **calls** that function and the compiler will not complain. That's probably why your textbook says *enables calls to the function before the function definition*.

Of course, you must then **define** the function somewhere (write the body of the function) for the program to execute correctly.

The text does not mean that the declaration is enough for it to work, it only states that declaring the function allows to write code that calls it without having the definition in place yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your book describes what we call a forward declaration.

> A forward declaration is a declaration of an identifier (denoting an entity such as a type, a variable, a constant, or a function) for which the programmer has not yet given a complete definition.

Source [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)

If you take a function declaration, it means you tell the compiler how your function will look like (function signature), so that you can call it in your code, but the compiler does not know yet what this function actually does.

**Example in C**

hello.h - *Function definition*

```
void helloWorld();
```

hello.m - *Function declaration*

```
void helloWorld() {
   printf("Hello World");
}
```

That is the reason why you have to include the .h files if you want to call the functions that are in there.

**Example in Objective C**

```
// I promise you (the compiler) that a class called MyClass exists
@class MyClass;
@interface MyInterface : NSObject {
    MyClass *evenThoughItDoesNotExistYet;
}
@end
```

**"Implicit" forward declaration**

Some other languages like ruby do this forward declaration internally. To achieve that, they scan the code multiple times to list all functions and then they validate if all functions called in the code exist.

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers for some languages need to know the signature of a function when it is first referenced in code.

Without prototypes, the programmer would have to write the definition of a function before it could be referenced.  This would make it impossible for two functions to mutually call each other.

Prototypes provide the compiler with the signature of a function that will be written (defined) later in the code, or possibly in a different code file.

Answer (score 0):

When the declaration is given, then the function can already be used, by code, for compilation. Later the definition of the function can be validated and compiled.

At runtime, the caller of the function (which was based on the declaration), is linked to the definition.

**Example in Java**

In Java an method in an interface can be seen as the declaration:

```
public interface IHelloWorld {

    void sayHello();

}
```

And a class implementing the method, which is declared in the interface, as the definition:

```
public class HelloWorld implements IHelloWorld {

    @Override
    public void sayHello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }

}
```

When another class uses the method in the interface, it has enough niformation to complete the compilation. At runtime it needs to get an instance of a concrete class, which implements the interface.

---

The same applies for an abstract class, which contains a method declaration:

```
public abstract class AbstractHelloWorld {

    public void sayHello(String name);

}
```

The concrete class would look like:

```
public class HelloWorld extends AbstractHelloWorld {

    @Override
    public void sayHello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }

}
```

Comment: The interface/implementation example is misleading.

Comment: @basgys Can you explain why it is misleading?

Comment: Your explanation and your example are two different things. The concept of interface in OO has nothing to do with functions declaration and implementation.

Comment: @basguys, In Java this is the _only_ way to show the concept. As methods can only be declare in the context of an interface or class. Other languages might indeed show the concept more cleaner.